# Pageable not work spring data MySQL Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I create dao layer using spring data as follow

```
 @Query(value="SELECT p FROM Products p INNER JOIN FETCH p.categoriesProducts cp INNER JOIN FETCH cp.categoryId c INNER JOIN FETCH p.mediasList ml ")
    public List<Products> getAllProduct(Pageable pageable);
```

and I call it as follow

```
PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(0,100) ; 
List<Products> ls = this.repo.getProductRepo().getAllProduct(pr) ;
```

my issue is I dont see the limit key word in the printed SQL in the log which is shown as follow

```
select products0_.id as id1_8_0_, categories1_.product_id as product_1_2_1_, categories2_.id as id1_1_2_, mediaslist3_.id as id1_4_3_, products0_.description as descript2_8_0_, products0_.discount_price as discount3_8_0_, products0_.price as price4_8_0_, products0_.prod_condition as prod_con5_8_0_, products0_.prod_number as prod_num6_8_0_, products0_.qty as qty7_8_0_, products0_.title as title8_8_0_, categories1_.category_id as category2_2_1_, categories2_.cat_name as cat_name2_1_2_, categories2_.description as descript3_1_2_, categories2_.keywords as keywords4_1_2_, categories2_.parent_id as parent_i5_1_2_, mediaslist3_.big_image_file as big_imag2_4_3_, mediaslist3_.media_type as media_ty3_4_3_, mediaslist3_.product_id as product_6_4_3_, mediaslist3_.thumb_image_file as thumb_im4_4_3_, mediaslist3_.video_file as video_fi5_4_3_, mediaslist3_.product_id as product_6_8_0__, mediaslist3_.id as id1_4_0__ from products products0_ inner join categories_products categories1_ on products0_.id=categories1_.product_id inner join categories categories2_ on categories1_.category_id=categories2_.id inner join medias mediaslist3_ on products0_.id=mediaslist3_.product_id
```

I am not sure what I do wrong the previous query is return 1000 rows from mysql and then it get the first 100 with the spring data but I need it to append limit 0,100 in the end of query, not sure how to do that

Comment: Because you are writing your own query the `Pageable` is ignored. Why not simply use the `findAll` which takes a `Pageable` argument? Assuming you are extending `JpaRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

Comment: I need this query because I have to join fetch the product data